# newcommand for index inserts unwanted spaces when using {}

Tags: indexing, makeindex

I'm creating a technical document with lots of index entries. To reduce typing I defined an index command that typesets the word to be indexed using `\emph{}`:

```
\newcommand{\ind}[1]{\index{#1@\emph{#1}}}
```

I turns out the `.ind` file gets different entries when I use this command, compared to typing the `\index{}` command myself: the entries created with the `\ind{}` command get two spaces inserted before the `{` of the `\emph` command. Consequently, the index will contain two entries for the same word if I use both the `\ind{}` command and the `\index{}` command (e.g. when defining a region using

```
\index{someword@\emph{someword}\(}
```

to start a region for that word.

Here is an MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\newcommand{\ind}[1]{\index{#1@\emph{#1}}}

\begin{document}
Testing our self-defined command\ind{italictext}. This is the
normal way\index{italictext@\emph{italictext}}.

\printindex
\end{document}
```

The contents of the `.ind` corresponding file is:

```
\begin{theindex}

  \item \emph  {italictext}, 1
  \item \emph{italictext}, 1

\end{theindex}
```

Note 1: my actual use case is not with `\emph{}`, but with `\lstinline{}` from the listings package, but this simplified example already shows the problem. I observed the same behaviour when using the `imakeidx` package.

Note 2: using `\DeclareRobustCommand` instead of `\newcommand` doesn't change anything.

Note 3: I am actually using a KOMA class documentclass, so the `scrindex` package would be an option since the spacing problem doesn't appear there (in fact, both entries end up as one index entry with a single space between the `\emph` and opening `{` in the `.ind` file. However, with that package I haven't managed to get the page numbers for the index entries hyperlinked when using the `hyperref` package.

Comment: I am not sure that `\lstinline` would work inside of `\index` however

Answer (score 7, accepted):

LaTeX's `\index` reads its argument as a verbatim argument to prevent the expansion of commands. If `\index` is used in the argument of another macro, then the argument of `\index` is already read and the switching to verbatim read mode of `\index` comes too late.

That `\index` is called in side `\ind` can be fixed by defining `\ind` in the same manner as `\index`, see its definition in `latex.ltx`:

```
\def\index{%
  \@bsphack % space handling around `\index`
  \begingroup % localize category code changes
  \@sanitize % change category codes to verbatim
  \@wrindex % reads argument, writes the index entry and ends the group
}
```

Example with new `\ind`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\ind}{%
  \@bsphack
  \begingroup
  \@sanitize
  \@ind
}
\newcommand*{\@ind}[1]{%
  \@wrindex{#1@\string\emph{#1}}%
}
\makeatletter

\begin{document}
Testing our self-defined command\ind{italictext}. This is the
normal way\index{italictext@\emph{italictext}}.

\printindex
\end{document}
```

Now, the two index entries (`.idx` file) are equal:

```
\indexentry{italictext@\emph{italictext}}{1}
\indexentry{italictext@\emph{italictext}}{1}
```

Comment: Thanks Heiko, your answer also works for my actual use case with `\lstinline`.

Answer (score 5):

You could use `\string\emph` inside of `\ind`, preventing a premature expansion of `\emph` etc. and insertion of a stray space character.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\newcommand{\ind}[1]{\index{#1@\string\emph{#1}}}
\begin{document}
Testing our self-defined command\ind{italictext}. This is the
normal way\index{italictext@\emph{italictext}}.

\printindex
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. However, adding `\string` doesn't seem to work. With the MWE I get one `italictext` entry (from the manual typing of `\index`) and one `“emphitalictext` entry. In the`.ind` file this entry is: `\item \string \emph {italictext}, 1`

Comment: @ph0t0nix: However, it works for me and there is only one entry, without `\string` etc

Comment: Sorry, you are right, it works as you described. When I tested I still had the `scrindex` package loaded instead of `makeidx`.

Comment: @ph0t0nix: Ah yes, the KOMA packages/classes introduces strange things sometimes...

Comment: as you expected, your answer doesn't work for my actual use case with `\lstinline`. Since Heiko Oberdiek's answer does work in that case, I'll accept that one. Nevertheless, thanks for the quick reply.