# Extra space in index entry

Tags: memoir, indexing

**Edit 2:** At the bottom I have updated the question after incorporating the answer from here: [newcommand for index inserts unwanted spaces when using {}](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/412517/newcommand-for-index-inserts-unwanted-spaces-when-using)

I created a function to display a command in bold with optionally giving the man page section in parenthesis.

```
\usepackage{xparse}
\newcommand*{\man}[2][]{%
   \textbf{#2}\IfNoValueF{#1}{(#1)}%
}
```

Now I also want to be able to create an index entry for these commands. So I created a wrapper command:

```
\newcommand*{\mani}[2][]{%
   \man[#1]{#2}%
   \index{#2@\man[#1]{#2}}%
}
```

However, sometimes I want to create an index entry using the same formatting, but not print the command in the running text. Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{xparse}
\newcommand*{\man}[2][]{%
   \textbf{#2}\IfNoValueF{#1}{(#1)}%
}
\newcommand*{\mani}[2][]{%
   \man[#1]{#2}%
   \index{#2@\man[#1]{#2}}%
}
\makeindex

\begin{document}
Only an index entry: \index{ssh-keygen@\man[1]{ssh-keygen}}
Hello world

Command and index entry: \mani[1]{ssh-keygen}

\printindex
\end{document}
```

The file `output.idx` contains two lines, the second containing an additional space. The question thus is, why is there an additional space and how can I fix it so there is no additional space?

```
\indexentry{ssh-keygen@\man[1]{ssh-keygen}}{1}
\indexentry{ssh-keygen@\man [1]{ssh-keygen}}{1}
```

**Edit 1:** I've added a screenshot of the result of this extra space: two identical index entries are printed.

[image: Double index entry]

## Update

I have updated my code as per the provided solution but I now get an error message which I do not understand.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{xparse}
\makeindex
\NewDocumentCommand\man{om}{%
   \textbf{#2}\IfNoValueF{#1}{(#1)}%
}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\mani}{%
   \@bsphack
   \begingroup
   \@sanitize
   \@mani
}
\newcommand*{\@mani}[2][]{%
   \man[#1]{#2}%
   \@wrindex{#2@\string\man[#1]{#2}}%
}
\makeatletter


\begin{document}
Two separate commands: \man[1]{ssh-keygen}\index{ssh-keygen@\man[1]{ssh-keygen}}
Hello world

One command: \mani[1]{ssh-keygen}

\printindex
\end{document}
```

OverLeaf states:

> The compiler is having trouble understanding a command you have used. Check that the command is spelled correctly. If the command is part of a package, make sure you have included the package in your preamble using \usepackage{...}.

The log file reports:

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   {
l.25     One command: \mani[1]{ssh-keygen}
                                          
A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)
```

Comment: Does the space actually cause an issue somewhere?

Comment: @PeterGrill: yes, I've updated my question with a screenshot of the issue at hand.

Comment: Unrelated to the question: `\newcommand` does _not_ provide the marker `NoValue`, so your use of `\IfNoValueF` might work by happy coincidence but you shouldn't do _that_. If you load `xparse` and use `IfNoValue` then you should use `\NewDocumentCommand` and its syntax.

Comment: I added the `memoir` tag, since the solution from the suggested duplicate breaks with `memoir`. If you switched to `article` + `\usepackage{makeidx}` as in the linked answer, things work. I tried chasing the relevant macros from `memoir`, but had to give up.

Comment: Not a duplicate, but one' explanation of the extra space in the `.idx` file: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/145309

Answer (score 1):

The command `\index` is expected to get its argument by reading and tokenizing things from the .tex-input file under `\@sanitize`-category-code-régime. (`\@sanitize`-category-code-régime means: Space-character, `\`, `$`, `&`, `#`, `^`, `_`, `%` and `~` have category code 12(other).) This is for several reasons—e.g.,

- avoiding unwanted expansion of expandable tokens.
- avoiding the appending of a space-character when unexpanded-writing a control-word-token to external file.

But with your command `\mani` the command `\index` does get its argument passed from `\mani`. When `\mani` gathers/composes `\index`'s argument, the tokens forming that argument are not tokenized under `\@sanitize`-category-code-régime but are tokenized under normal category-code-régime.

Beneath other things tokenizing under normal category-code-régime implies that phrases like `\man` get tokenized as control-word-tokens, not as character-sequences `\`, `m`, `a`, `n`. When control-word-tokens get written unexpanded to text-file, e.g., some `.idx`-file belonging to the process of creating the index, a space-character will be appended. I.e., the character-sequence `\`, `m`, `a`, `n`, `⟨space character⟩` will be written.

Within the definition of `\mani` you can apply `\string` to the command `\man` in order to turn it into a sequence of character-tokens. (Hereby it is relied on only one input-character having category code 0 (escape) and the value of the integer-parameter `\escapechar` being equal to the number of the code-point of that character in the TeX-engine's internal character-encoding-scheme. Usually the backslash-character `\` is the only character of category code 0(escape) and usually `\escapechar` has the value 92 which is the number of the backslash-character's code-point in the TeX-engine's internal character-encoding-scheme.)

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentCommand{\man}{om}{%
   \textbf{#2}\IfNoValueF{#1}{(#1)}%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\mani}{om}{%
   \IfNoValueTF{#1}{%
      \man{#2}%
      \index{#2@\string\man{#2}}%
    }{%
      \man[#1]{#2}%
      \index{#2@\string\man[#1]{#2}}%
    }%
}%
\makeindex

\begin{document}

Only an index entry: \index{ssh-keygen@\man[1]{ssh-keygen}}
Hello world

Command and index entry: \mani[1]{ssh-keygen}

Only an index entry: \index{ssh-keygen-no-optional-argument@\man{ssh-keygen-no-optional-argument}}
Hello world

Command and index entry: \mani{ssh-keygen-no-optional-argument}

\printindex
\end{document}
```

With the example above the resulting .idx-file looks like this:

```
\indexentry{ssh-keygen@\man[1]{ssh-keygen}}{1}
\indexentry{ssh-keygen@\man[1]{ssh-keygen}}{1}
\indexentry{ssh-keygen-no-optional-argument@\man{ssh-keygen-no-optional-argument}}{1}
\indexentry{ssh-keygen-no-optional-argument@\man{ssh-keygen-no-optional-argument}}{1}
```

With this approach, the only thing "stringified" within the argument of `\index`, which is supplied via the macro `\mani`, is the phrase `\man`.

Things that come from `\mani`'s first or second argument are not stringified. In case the sets of tokens supplied via these arguments also contain control-word-tokens, you might get unwanted spaces here, too.

I can offer a routine `\StringifyNAct` which applies `\string` to each token within its argument:

```
\StringifyNAct{⟨action⟩}{⟨token 1⟩⟨token 2⟩...⟨token n⟩}
```

yields:

```
⟨action⟩{⟨stringification of token 1⟩}%
⟨action⟩{⟨stringification of token 2⟩}%
...
⟨action⟩{⟨stringification of token n⟩}%
```

whereby "stringification of token" means the result of applying `\string` to the token in question.
Due to `\romannumeral`-expansion the result is delivered by triggering two expansion-steps (e.g., via two `\expandafter`-chains).

I suggest the command `\mani` to read and tokenize its arguments under normal category-code-régime, but with the space-character (and probably also the horizontal-tab-character, addressable as `^^I` with TeX's `^^`-notation) being of category-code 12(other), then to apply `\StringifyNAct` to the arguments, then passing the result thereof to the `\index`-command and—nested in `\scantokens`—to the `\man`-command:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\makeatletter
%%========================Code for \StringifyNAct==============================
%%
%% Copyright (C) 2019, 2020 by Ulrich Diez (ud.usenetcorrespondence@web.de)
%%
%% This work may be distributed and/or modified under the
%% conditions of the LaTeX Project Public Licence (LPPL), either
%% version 1.3 of this license or (at your option) any later
%% version. (The latest version of this license is in:
%% http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
%% and version 1.3 or later is part of all distributions of LaTeX
%% version 1999/12/01 or later.)
%% The author of this work is Ulrich Diez.
%% This work has the LPPL maintenance status 'not maintained'.
%% Usage of any/every component of this work is at your own risk.
%% There is no warranty - neither for probably included
%% documentation nor for any other part/component of this work.
%% If something breaks, you usually may keep the pieces.
%%
%%=============================================================================
%% Paraphernalia:
%%    \UD@firstoftwo, \UD@secondoftwo,
%%    \UD@PassFirstToSecond, \UD@Exchange, \UD@removespace
%%    \UD@CheckWhetherNull, \UD@CheckWhetherBrace,
%%    \UD@CheckWhetherLeadingSpace, \UD@ExtractFirstArg
%%=============================================================================
\newcommand\UD@firstoftwo[2]{#1}%
\newcommand\UD@secondoftwo[2]{#2}%
\newcommand\UD@PassFirstToSecond[2]{#2{#1}}%
\newcommand\UD@Exchange[2]{#2#1}%
\newcommand\UD@removespace{}\UD@firstoftwo{\def\UD@removespace}{} {}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Check whether argument is empty:
%%.............................................................................
%% \UD@CheckWhetherNull{<Argument which is to be checked>}%
%%                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                       which is to be checked is empty>}%
%%                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                       which is to be checked is not empty>}%
%%
%% The gist of this macro comes from Robert R. Schneck's \ifempty-macro:
%% <https://groups.google.com/forum/#!original/comp.text.tex/kuOEIQIrElc/lUg37FmhA74J>
\newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherNull[1]{%
  \romannumeral0\expandafter\UD@secondoftwo\string{\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter{\string#1}\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\UD@firstoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\expandafter\UD@firstoftwo{ }{}%
  \UD@secondoftwo}{\expandafter\expandafter\UD@firstoftwo{ }{}\UD@firstoftwo}%
}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Check whether argument's first token is a catcode-1-character
%%.............................................................................
%% \UD@CheckWhetherBrace{<Argument which is to be checked>}%
%%                      {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                        which is to be checked has leading
%%                        catcode-1-token>}%
%%                      {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                        which is to be checked has no leading
%%                        catcode-1-token>}%
\newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherBrace[1]{%
  \romannumeral0\expandafter\UD@secondoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter{%
  \string#1.}\expandafter\UD@firstoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\expandafter\UD@firstoftwo{ }{}%
  \UD@firstoftwo}{\expandafter\expandafter\UD@firstoftwo{ }{}\UD@secondoftwo}%
}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Check whether brace-balanced argument starts with a space-token
%%.............................................................................
%% \UD@CheckWhetherLeadingSpace{<Argument which is to be checked>}%
%%                             {<Tokens to be delivered in case <argument
%%                               which is to be checked>'s 1st token is a
%%                               space-token>}%
%%                             {<Tokens to be delivered in case <argument
%%                               which is to be checked>'s 1st token is not
%%                               a space-token>}%
\newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherLeadingSpace[1]{%
  \romannumeral0\UD@CheckWhetherNull{#1}%
  {\expandafter\expandafter\UD@firstoftwo{ }{}\UD@secondoftwo}%
  {\expandafter\UD@secondoftwo\string{\UD@CheckWhetherLeadingSpaceB.#1 }{}}%
}%
\newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherLeadingSpaceB{}%
\long\def\UD@CheckWhetherLeadingSpaceB#1 {%
  \expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherNull\expandafter{\UD@secondoftwo#1{}}%
  {\UD@Exchange{\UD@firstoftwo}}{\UD@Exchange{\UD@secondoftwo}}%
  {\UD@Exchange{ }{\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
   \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter}\expandafter\expandafter
   \expandafter}\expandafter\UD@secondoftwo\expandafter{\string}%
}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Extract first inner undelimited argument:
%%
%%   \UD@ExtractFirstArg{ABCDE} yields  {A}
%%
%%   \UD@ExtractFirstArg{{AB}CDE} yields  {AB}
%%.............................................................................
\newcommand\UD@RemoveTillUD@SelDOm{}%
\long\def\UD@RemoveTillUD@SelDOm#1#2UD@SelDOm{{#1}}%
\newcommand\UD@ExtractFirstArg[1]{%
  \romannumeral0%
  \UD@ExtractFirstArgLoop{#1UD@SelDOm}%
}%
\newcommand\UD@ExtractFirstArgLoop[1]{%
  \expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherNull\expandafter{\UD@firstoftwo{}#1}%
  { #1}%
  {\expandafter\UD@ExtractFirstArgLoop\expandafter{\UD@RemoveTillUD@SelDOm#1}}%
}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------    
%% In case an argument's first token is an opening brace, stringify that and
%% add another opening brace before that and remove everything behind the 
%% matching closing brace:
%% \UD@StringifyOpeningBrace{{Foo}bar} yields {{Foo}  whereby the second
%% opening brace is stringified:
%%.............................................................................
\newcommand\UD@StringifyOpeningBrace[1]{%
  \romannumeral0%
  \expandafter\UD@ExtractFirstArgLoop\expandafter{%
    \romannumeral0\UD@Exchange{ }{\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter}%
    \expandafter\expandafter
    \expandafter            {%
    \expandafter\UD@firstoftwo
    \expandafter{%
    \expandafter}%
    \romannumeral0\UD@Exchange{ }{\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter}%
    \expandafter\string
    \expandafter}%
    \string#1%
  UD@SelDOm}%
}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------    
%% In case an argument's first token is an opening brace, remove everything till 
%% finding the corresponding closing brace. Then stringify that closing brace:
%% \UD@StringifyClosingBrace{{Foo}bar} yields: {}bar} whereby the first closing
%% brace is stringified:
%%.............................................................................
\newcommand\UD@StringifyClosingBrace[1]{%
   \romannumeral0\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
                 \UD@StringifyClosingBraceloop
                 \UD@ExtractFirstArg{#1}{#1}%
}%
\newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherStringifiedOpenBraceIsSpace[1]{%
%% This can happen when character 32 (space) has catcode 1...
  \expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherLeadingSpace\expandafter{%
    \romannumeral0\UD@Exchange{ }{\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter}%
    \expandafter\UD@secondoftwo
    \expandafter{%
    \expandafter}%
    \expandafter{%
    \romannumeral0\UD@Exchange{ }{\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter}%
    \expandafter\UD@firstoftwo
    \expandafter{%
    \expandafter}%
    \romannumeral0\UD@Exchange{ }{\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter}%
    \expandafter\string
    \expandafter}%
    \string#1%
  }%
}%
\newcommand\UD@TerminateStringifyClosingBraceloop[2]{%
  \UD@Exchange{ }{\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter}%
  \expandafter\expandafter
  \expandafter{%
  \expandafter\string      
  \romannumeral0\UD@Exchange{ }{\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter}%
  \expandafter#1%
  \string#2%
  }%
}%
\newcommand\UD@StringifyClosingBraceloopRemoveElement[4]{%
  \expandafter\UD@PassFirstToSecond\expandafter{\expandafter
  {\romannumeral0\expandafter\UD@secondoftwo\string}{}%
    \UD@CheckWhetherStringifiedOpenBraceIsSpace{#4}{%
      \UD@Exchange{\UD@removespace}%
    }{%
      \UD@Exchange{\UD@firstoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter}}%
    }{%
      \UD@Exchange{ }{\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter}%
      \expandafter#1%
      \romannumeral0\UD@Exchange{ }{\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter}%
      \expandafter
    }%
    \string#4%
  }{\expandafter\UD@StringifyClosingBraceloop\expandafter{#2#3}}%
}%
\newcommand\UD@StringifyClosingBraceloop[2]{%
  \UD@CheckWhetherNull{#1}{%
    \UD@CheckWhetherStringifiedOpenBraceIsSpace{#2}{%
      \UD@TerminateStringifyClosingBraceloop{\UD@removespace}%
    }{%
      \UD@TerminateStringifyClosingBraceloop{\UD@firstoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter}}%
    }%
    {#2}%
  }{%
    \UD@CheckWhetherLeadingSpace{#1}{%
      \UD@StringifyClosingBraceloopRemoveElement
      {\UD@removespace}{\UD@removespace}%
    }{%
      \UD@StringifyClosingBraceloopRemoveElement
      {\UD@firstoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter}}{\UD@firstoftwo{}}%
    }%
    {#1}{#2}%
  }%
}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------    
%% Apply <action> to the stringification of each token of the argument:
%%
%% \StringifyNAct{<action>}{<token 1><token 2>...<token n>}
%%
%% yields:  <action>{<stringification of token 1>}%
%%          <action>{<stringification of token 2>}%
%%          ...
%%          <action>{<stringification of token n>}%
%%
%% whereby "stringification of token" means the result of applying \string
%% to the token in question.
%% Due to \romannumeral-expansion the result is delivered after two
%% \expandafter-chains.
%% If you leave <action> empty, you can apply a loop on the list formed by
%%   {<stringification of token 1>}%
%%   {<stringification of token 2>}%
%%   ...
%%   {<stringification of token n>}%
%%
%% Below a macro \ConcatenateStringifiedtokens is implemented which loops
%% on that list for concatenating.
%%.............................................................................
\newcommand\StringifyNAct{%
  \romannumeral0\StringifyNActLoop{}%
}%
%%.............................................................................
%% \StringifyNActLoop{{<stringification of token 1>}...{<stringification of token k-1>}}%
%%                   {<action>}%
%%                   {<token k>...<token n>}
%%.............................................................................
\newcommand\StringifyNActLoop[3]{%
  \UD@CheckWhetherNull{#3}{%
    \UD@firstoftwo{ }{}#1%
  }{%
    \UD@CheckWhetherBrace{#3}{%
      \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\UD@Exchange
      \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
        \UD@StringifyClosingBrace{#3}%
      }{%
        \expandafter\StringifyNActLoop\expandafter{%
          \romannumeral0%
          \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\UD@Exchange
          \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\UD@StringifyOpeningBrace{#3}}{\StringifyNActLoop{#1}{#2}}%
        }{#2}%
      }%
    }{%
      \UD@CheckWhetherLeadingSpace{#3}{%
        \expandafter\UD@PassFirstToSecond\expandafter{\UD@removespace#3}{%
          \StringifyNActLoop{#1#2{ }}{#2}%
        }%
      }{%
        \expandafter\UD@PassFirstToSecond\expandafter{\UD@firstoftwo{}#3}{%
          \expandafter\StringifyNActLoop\expandafter{%
             \romannumeral0%
             \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\UD@PassFirstToSecond
             \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
               \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\string
               \expandafter\UD@Exchange
               \romannumeral0\UD@ExtractFirstArgLoop{#3UD@SelDOm}{}%
             }{ #1#2}%
          }%
          {#2}%
        }%
      }%
    }%
  }%
}%
%% The promised loop for concatenating stringified tokens - apply as:
%%
%%      \romannumeral0%
%%      \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
%%      \ConcatenateStringifiedtokens
%%      \StringifyNAct{}{<tokens to stringify>}\relax
%%
\newcommand*\ConcatenateStringifiedtokens{%
  \ConcatenateStringifiedtokensloop{ }%
}%
\newcommand\ConcatenateStringifiedtokensloop[2]{%
  \ifx\relax#2\expandafter\@firstoftwo\else\expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi
  {#1}{%
    \ConcatenateStringifiedtokensloop{#1#2}%
  }%
}%
%%=================== End of code for \StringifyNAct ==========================
\makeatother

\usepackage{xparse}

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\man}{om}{%
   \UD@CheckWhetherNull{#2}{}{%
     \toks@{#2}%
     \textbf{\the\toks@}%
   }%
   \IfNoValueF{#1}{(#1)}%
}%
\NewDocumentCommand{\mani}{}{%
  \begingroup
  \catcode`\ =12\relax
  \catcode`\^^I=12\relax
  \maniinner
}%
\NewDocumentCommand{\maniinner}{om}{%
   \endgroup
   \IfNoValueTF{#1}{%
      \expandafter\maniinnerinner\expandafter{%
        \romannumeral0%
        \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
        \ConcatenateStringifiedtokens
        \StringifyNAct{}{#2}\relax
      }%
    }{%
      \expandafter\UD@PassFirstToSecond\expandafter{%
        \romannumeral0%
        \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
        \ConcatenateStringifiedtokens
        \StringifyNAct{}{#2}\relax
      }{%
        \expandafter\maniinnerinner\expandafter[\expandafter{%
          \romannumeral0%
          \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
          \ConcatenateStringifiedtokens
          \StringifyNAct{}{#1}\relax
        }]%
      }%
    }%
}%
\makeatother
\begingroup
\newcommand\maniinnerinner[1]{%
  \endgroup
  \NewDocumentCommand{\maniinnerinner}{om}{%
     \IfNoValueTF{##1}{%
        \scantokens{\man{##2}#1}%
        \index{##2@\string\man{##2}}%
      }{%
        \scantokens{\man[##1]{##2}#1}%
        \index{##2@\string\man[##1]{##2}}%
      }%
  }%
}%
\catcode`\%=12\relax
\maniinnerinner{%}%

\makeindex

\begin{document}

Only an index entry: \index{ssh-keygen@\man[1]{ssh-keygen}}
Hello world

Command and index entry: \mani[1]{ssh-keygen}

Only an index entry: \index{ssh-keygen-no-optional-argument@\man{ssh-keygen-no-optional-argument}}
Hello world

Command and index entry: \mani{ssh-keygen-no-optional-argument}

\newcommand\ke{ke}%
\newcommand\one{1}%

Only an index entry: \index{ssh-\ke y\string#gen@\man[\one]{ssh-\ke y\string#gen}}
Hello world

Command and index entry: \mani[\one]{ssh-\ke y\string#gen}


\printindex
\end{document}
```

With the example above the resulting .idx-file looks like this:

```
\indexentry{ssh-keygen@\man[1]{ssh-keygen}}{1}
\indexentry{ssh-keygen@\man[1]{ssh-keygen}}{1}
\indexentry{ssh-keygen-no-optional-argument@\man{ssh-keygen-no-optional-argument}}{1}
\indexentry{ssh-keygen-no-optional-argument@\man{ssh-keygen-no-optional-argument}}{1}
\indexentry{ssh-\ke y\string#gen@\man[\one]{ssh-\ke y\string#gen}}{1}
\indexentry{ssh-\ke y\string#gen@\man[\one]{ssh-\ke y\string#gen}}{1}
```

Answer (score 1):

The name of the `\write`-handle used for the .idx-file with memoir differs from the name of the `\write`-handle used with the LaTeX 2ε-macro `\@wrindex`.

Thus you need to map the name of the "kernel-`\write`-handle" for the index to the "memoir-`\write`-handle" for the index:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{xparse}
\makeindex
\NewDocumentCommand\man{om}{%
   \textbf{#2}\IfNoValueF{#1}{(#1)}%
}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\mani}{%
   \@bsphack
   \begingroup
   \@sanitize
   \@mani
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\@mani}{om}{%
   \@ifundefined{@indexfile}{%
     \expandafter\let\expandafter\@indexfile\csname\jobname @idxfile\endcsname
   }{}%
   \IfNoValueTF{#1}{%
     \man{#2}%
     \@wrindex{#2@\string\man{#2}}%
   }{%
     \man[#1]{#2}%
     \@wrindex{#2@\string\man[#1]{#2}}%
   }%
}
\makeatletter

\begin{document}
Two separate commands: \man[1]{ssh-keygen}\index{ssh-keygen@\man[1]{ssh-keygen}}
Hello world

One command: \mani[1]{ssh-keygen}

\printindex
\end{document}
```

The .idx-file looks like this:

```
\indexentry{ssh-keygen@\man[1]{ssh-keygen}}{1}
\indexentry{ssh-keygen@\man[1]{ssh-keygen}}{1}
```

**Be aware that—unlike the approach of stringification after tokenization presented in my other answer—`\@sanitize` does not handle the balancing of curly braces in case the arguments of `\mani` are to contain the control-symbol-token `\{` and/or the control-symbol-token `\}`.**