# Additional spaces in .ind and .idx files

Tags: xetex, makeindex

I am really noob with LaTeX, and I am running into an issue with an index:

In the .ind / .idx files, spaces are added to some entries, for a reason I cannnot figure. For instance, while the .tex file has

```
\index[IndexInterp]{\textbf{Bethsames }! domus ueri solis}
```

in the .ind file this entry becomes:

```
\item \textbf  {Bethsames }
\subitem  domus ueri solis, 279
```

As a result, this entry does not appear in the right place according to the alphabetical order.

I would be grateful if you had a way to fix this.
I work with TeXWorks on Windows 10, and typeset with XelateX

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  This q&a may help: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/412517

Comment: Thank you @barbarabeeton adding \string seems to have solved the issue! 
I still don't understand why those strings appeared though, because contrary to the poster in this example I had not redefined the \index command.

Comment: as always your question would be clearer if you had provided an example that demonstrated the problem.I would guess that you have used `\index` in the argument of another command. Also, you have redefined `\index` somewhere despite your comment above, the standard `\index` command does not have an optional argument.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle -- An optional argument is characteristic of `imakeindex`.  And a very nice option it is.  (Don't know whether it's what's relevant here; as you said, no example to tie it down.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton there are probably a dozen packages extending index and most give index an optional argument, but we shouldn't have to guess which is used