# How can I get exactly one space in .idx? I know how to get two or none, but not just one

Tags: spacing, indexing, catcodes, makeindex

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{ltxdoc}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*\myindex[3]{%
  \doc@providetarget
  \index{#1:\levelchar#2\actualchar{\ttfamily#3}\doc@handleencap{usage}}%
}
\makeatother

\makeindex
        
\begin{document}

\DescribeEnv{myenv}\marg{argument}\par

\myindex{environments}{myenv}{myenv}
    
\end{document}
```

While `\DescribeEnv` indexes `myenv` with just a single space before `myenv`, `\myindex` adds two.

Contents of `.idx`:

```
\indexentry{myenv={\ttfamily myenv} (env.)|hdclindex{2}{usage}}{1}
\indexentry{environments:>myenv={\ttfamily myenv}|hdclindex{2}{usage}}{1}
\indexentry{environments:>myenv={\ttfamily  myenv}|hdclindex{3}{usage}}{1}
```

This results in twice as many index entries as there should be.

Thanks to [Heiko Oberdiek's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/412521/) I can prevent this using

```
\documentclass{ltxdoc}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*\myindex[3]{% ateb Heiko Oberdiek https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/412521/
  \doc@providetarget
  \@bsphack
  \begingroup
  \@sanitize
  \@wrindex{#1:\levelchar#2\actualchar{\string\ttfamily #3}\doc@handleencap{usage}}%
}
\makeatother

\makeindex
        
\begin{document}

\DescribeEnv{myenv}\marg{argument}\par

\myindex{environments}{myenv}{myenv}

\end{document}
```

which gives me

```
\indexentry{myenv={\ttfamily myenv} (env.)|hdclindex{2}{usage}}{1}
\indexentry{environments:>myenv={\ttfamily myenv}|hdclindex{2}{usage}}{1}
\indexentry{environments:>myenv={\ttfamilymyenv}|hdclindex{3}{usage}}{1}
```

but now I have no spaces and I cannot figure out how to keep exactly one. In case it matters, I'm actually doing this with `expl3` syntax on, though I could avoid that if necessary.

Comment: `{\string\ttfamily\space #3}` should work.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I could have sworn I tried that, but you're absolutely right. Thank you again.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Do I need `\endgroup` somewhere or does `\@wrindex` do that? I've copy-pasted this, but I don't really know what these commands do.

Comment: the \endgroup is in the \@wrindex (in latex, I didn't check the various packages).